# Programmatically changing colors doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

In nextjs, I have a list of colors and a function that takes a number as an argument and returns a component styled by Tailwindcss that has a distinct color using that number.

```js
const listColors = ["lime", "teal", "violet"]

function getStyle(idx: number) {
    const color = listColors[idx % listColors.length];
    return `bg-${color}-500 text-${color}-100`;
}

export default function TestComponent({text, idx} : {text: string, idx: number}) {
    return (
        <div className={getStyle(idx)}>
            {text}
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, this code does **not** change the color of the component. I thought this was because the style was not a string literal, so I tried using the following code:

```js
return 'bg-' + color + '-500 text-' + color + '-100';
```

This ended up not working too. However, if I explicitly write the color name, it works

```js
return 'bg-teal-500 text-teal-100';
```

Why does explicitly writing the name of the color work while programmatically using the color does not?

Comment: The short of the answer above is you can't do this with tailwind.  It scans for classnames it should use, so it only works on unbroken strings https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: I changed the colorList to say instead:
const bgColors = ["bg-lime-500", "bg-teal-500", "bg-violet-500"]
const textColors = ["text-lime-100", "text-teal-100", "text-violet-100"]
and it works, but this method seems unnecessarily wordy.. However reading the document makes it seem this is the only way to make the program work... thank you everybody :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tailwind scans for unbroken strings to include for classes, so string interpolation doesn't work

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

For your case, you can replace the class generation with an object and keep the interface you had

```
const colorClasses = {
    lime: "bg-lime-500 text-lime-100",
    teal: "bg-teal-500 text-teal-100",
    violet: "bg-violet-500 text-violet-100",
};

function getStyle(idx: number) {
    const colorKeys = Object.keys(colorClasses);
    const colorKey = colorKeys[idx % colorKeys.length];
    return colorClasses[colorKey];
}
```